# Django : Do you need to name a tag library (templates, static, etc) with a specific folder name?

Tags: python, html, django, templates, web

So, I'm currently learning Django.
And I got confused when I started creating, for example, 'templates' folder. So templates folder is where we can actually store templates for the web application.
Do we actually need to name the folder 'templates'? Or could we name it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use name 'templates' and with a subfolder name of your Django app like blog/templates/blog and save your HTML files in this and if you wanna save your CSS and js files do same but this time choose name static as blog/static/blog where blog is may be your app name , if you're a beginner and if you've done with Django before then you can change your settings.py in project folder

Comment: Thanks so much, it really helps

Answer (score 0):

You can name it to anything but be aware of locating that folder location in the settings.py otherwise Django will not look at the folder.

For further reference use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/).

Comment: Thank youuu, this helpss